# 0x20 treated as 0x00 with stringstream

Tags: c++

The following program writes 0x20 to stringstream, then reads the value and it's 0. Why is that and how to write a value so it is read as 0x20?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << (char) 0x20;
  char c;
  ss >> c;
  if ( c == 0x20 ) {
    std::cout << "32";
  } else if ( c == 0 ) {
    std::cout << "0";
  } else {
    std::cout << "other";
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `ss >> std::noskipws >> c;` it reads whitespace. By default, any whitespaces are discarded when reading by formatted operation.

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `std::stringstream`'s `>>` operator skips over writespace. And in ASCII (a typical but by no means universal encoding). `0x20` is the space character you get when you press that long button on your keyboard.

As there is nothing else on the stream, NUL is output to `c`.

Introducing the manipulator `std::noskipws` is the fix; that is `ss >> std::noskipws >> c;` reads the value as 0x20.